# detect button click globally

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

In android, is there anyway to detect that a foreground app's button is clicked? I am not talking about my own app, I mean detect globally a button press event.

For exapmle, skype is running in foreground, I'd like to detect when user clicked a button in skype.

=====UPDATE=====

If the answer of above question is no, is there a way to detect window focus change OR dialog popup globally?

Comment: maybe if they globally broadcast the event *this button was pressed*, but I think the general answer is *no*

Comment: Are you talk in about __Chat Face like Facebook__?

Comment: I don't know what Chat Face is, but what I am talking about should be clear in my question. i.e. Detect globally some events e.g. button click / dialog popup / window focus change.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is *no* and *no*.

That is by design and it's a "security feature". Android is sandboxed, apps operate on separate `Window`s and separate processes and are not supposed to know about each other. Unless the specific app is broadcasting something, there's no way to external apps to access it.

Try to imagine what a HUGE security flaw that would be to have that type of access.

- malicious code is installed with permission to receive "global clicks" and "draw on top of other apps".
- user installs banking app
- user click on `login` on banking app
- malicious code receive the click and draw on top of the app something that looks exactly like the banking app
- user type his/her login details
- malicious code transmit user details to remote server
- developer of malicious code withdraw users money.

to conclude: I'm very happy that Android does not provide such functionality.